# Добавление контакта в телефон

Tags: java, android

Можно в своем приложении реализовать добавление телефонного контакта в список телефонных контактов телефона?

Если да, то как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, [можно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4744514/7129209).

Не забудьте добавить в `AndroidManifest.xml` соответствующее разрешение:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
```

А если у Вас `targetSdk >= 23`, то не забудьте запросить это разрешение в рантайме, так как оно относится к категории dangerous.

```
String DisplayName = "XYZ";
String MobileNumber = "123456";
String HomeNumber = "1111";
String WorkNumber = "2222";
String emailID = "email@nomail.com";
String company = "bad";
String jobTitle = "abcd";

ArrayList <ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList <ContentProviderOperation>();

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(
ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
 .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
 .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
 .build());

//------------------------------------------------------ Names
if (DisplayName != null) {
 ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(
 ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
     .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
     .withValue(
 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
 DisplayName).build());
}

//------------------------------------------------------ Mobile Number                     
if (MobileNumber != null) {
 ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.
 newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
     .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, MobileNumber)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
     .build());
}

//------------------------------------------------------ Home Numbers
if (HomeNumber != null) {
 ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
     .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, HomeNumber)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME)
     .build());
}

//------------------------------------------------------ Work Numbers
if (WorkNumber != null) {
 ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
     .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, WorkNumber)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK)
     .build());
}

//------------------------------------------------------ Email
if (emailID != null) {
 ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
     .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, emailID)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK)
     .build());
}

//------------------------------------------------------ Organization
if (!company.equals("") && !jobTitle.equals("")) {
 ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
     .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY, company)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE_WORK)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE, jobTitle)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE_WORK)
     .build());
}

// Asking the Contact provider to create a new contact                 
try {
 getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
} catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 Toast.makeText(myContext, "Exception: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ!